# I keep reviewing my questions so that they are not downvoted, but nothing I do helps

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I am trying to improve [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815108/how-to-properly-retrieve-a-json-string-with-php) score but nothing that I do seems to get the "-2" away. I've changed the title and rephrased the question but ultimate nothing changes. Can anyone give me some hints on what to do on that question?

Also I just got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143712/pdf-indexer-rokajaxsearch-where-can-i-find-the-function-that-displays-the-pd) closed. I have read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and I am asking a question that references a commonly used CMS and plug-ins. There are far worse question being asked out there that are not closed. I really need the answer to that question.

Comment: Check my edit to your first question, it's _extremely_ minor, but plz never write plz again...

Comment: I'm glad you're trying to improve--Just looking over it briefly, there are a few things that you can easily improve without too much effort. In part, consider spelling out words like "please" for "plz". Also, don't put "thanks" into a question, since it's considered noise.

Comment: With regards to your closed question (now reopened), I'm not sure "off topic" is what I would have said there, but you're not giving us much to go on. "Not a real question" might have been my idea. My lack of knowledge in the domain might be the cause, but it feels to be "not answerable in its current form".

Comment: Thank you for the tips. How about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181651/code-not-responding-accordingly-to-the-parameters-passed-via-the-browser has a -2... Now that someone highlighted the problem i can see how silly the issue was.... but at the time I couldnt see the problem myself.... why do i have -2?

Comment: `There are far worse question being asked out there that are not closed` Other questions are entirely irrelevant to the matter.  It's possible that the other questions are poor, but don't actually meet any criteria for closing (just downvoting), it's possible that they just haven't gotten enough attention to be closed, despite being close-worthy, or it's possible that they're older questions from when the guidelines for closing a question were less strict (in which case they will be closed now if they get enough attention).  All that matters is whether your question meets the close criteria.

Answer (score 6):

> *I am trying to improve my question score but nothing that I do seems to get the "-2" away.*

Some (most?) downvoters don't (can't?) re-read edited questions in order to remove the downvote.

I admit that I am myself also guilty in this. But there exist so far now *no* notification system wherein the downvoter would be notified about a possible improvement of the question so that the vote could be reconsidered. This way the downvotes will, unfortunately, "never" go away.

Answer (score 2):

To refer solely to [Code not responding accordingly to the parameters passed via the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181651/code-not-responding-accordingly-to-the-parameters-passed-via-the-browser), which you linked to in the comments.

You posted *a lot* of code. Too much. Had you created a [short, self-contained, example](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate your problem chances are you would have seen the error and been able to correct it. Using italics to highlight error messages also made the top of the question fairly difficult to read. If you look at my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12181651/revisions) I've added more whitespace to try to clearly define what's happening. I've also removed *"Thank you guys!"* from the post as this is [unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

I can only guess at the reasons for the downvotes as I can't speak for other voters. However, I would guess that someone downvoted either because the question is too difficult to understand or because you don't appear to have put much effort into solving the problem yourself.

I would like to emphasise that the amount of code was unnecessary. It appears as though you dumped a load of your project into a question and left someone else to solve the problem, which doesn't endear you to people.

I recognise that you may not see it that way but you're *not* the person answering the question. You *have* to look at your question as an answerer would to see whether it makes sense and you've provided the correct information. It's a skill I haven't mastered by any stretch of the imagination but there are plenty of good resources out there.

Here's a couple of the most commonly linked ones, which would be worth reading:

- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Full disclosure:
I have voted to close this question as too localized as the problem was simply a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to improve my question score but nothing that I do seems to get the "-2" away.

As Chichiray said, users don't get any notification for edits done on posts they voted. You could have significantly improved your question, but they don't know it, if they don't watch again your question.

It could also mean that who down-voted thinks your question doesn't show any search effort, it is not useful, or it is not clear. (That is what appear in the tooltip for the down-vote button.) In the last case, it could be they still think your question is not clear.